# Serialise list of C# custom objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I am receiving a JSON string from API that is structured in not a good way to be handled in the App.

I chose to create a custom serialiser for this JSON data (rather then having two different classes for data received and used in app).

Following a lot of tutorials I managed to put together a custom serialiser for a single object. However, I need to work with lists of these objects (there will be more different data that will come in these weird lists, that needs custom handling).

Is there a built in way I can set my custom serialiser to work with each object in the list? Or do I need to split the JSON object manually, and feed chunks of it to custom serialiser?

Any other suggestions how to handle this situation is appreciated.

User class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(UserSerializer))]
    public class User
    {
        public int id;
        public string displayName;
        public string email;
        public int total_points;
        public float total_values;
    }
```

The deserialiser:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jObjectRoot = JObject.Load(reader);
            var root = jObjectRoot.Properties().ToList();
            JObject jObjectData = JObject.Load(root[2].Value.CreateReader());
            var data = jObjectData.Properties().ToList();
            return new User { 
                id = (int)root[1].Value,
                displayName = (string)data[0].Value,
                email = (string)data[1].Value,
                total_points = (int)data[2].Value,
                total_values = (float)data[3].Value
            };
        }
```

UPDATE:

Also the code that parses the json string to single user object:

```
public static void ProcessJSON(string json)
{
    User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
}
```

And the JSON itself:

```
[
  {
    "type": "users",
    "id": 1,
    "attr": {
      "display_name": "user2",
      "email": "user2@email.com",
      "total_points": 4,
      "total_values": 32.34
    },
    "relationships": {
      "points_received": {
        "links": {
          "self": "tipjar/users/1/relationships/points",
          "related": "tipjar/users/1/points"
        }
      },
      "points_given": {
        "links": {
          "self": "tipjar/users/1/relationships/awarded",
          "related": "tipjar/users/1/awarded"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at using Newtonsoft JSON.NET?

Comment: How does the JSON look?

Comment: @GlenThomas Yes, I am using Newtonsoft JSON.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of user objects without a custom converter like this:

```
var userList = JArray.Parse(json)
    .Select(t => new User()
    {
        id = int.Parse(t["id"].ToString()),
        displayName = t["attr"]["display_name"].ToString(),
        email = t["attr"]["email"].ToString(),
        total_points = int.Parse(t["attr"]["total_points"].ToString()),
        total_values = float.Parse(t["attr"]["total_values"].ToString()),
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Lol this works like a charm, without writing complex converters. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As a minor improvement, Json.Net supports casting `JValues` directly to their corresponding primitive types, so you can do `total_points = (int)t["attr"]["total_points"]` instead of using `ToString()` and then `int.Parse()`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void ProcessJSON(string json)
{
    User u = new User();
    var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    if (test.GetType() == typeof(User))
        u = (User)test;

}
```

Not 100% on how the serialize works, but this seemed to have worked on the test app I made.

It might be a bit silly. But you could test on the different types of objects returned...

Comment: Sorry, this will not work at all.  If you don't specify a type in `DeserializeObject` then it will be a `JToken` of some kind, which is not a `User`.  So the user `u` will always have default values.  Even if you did specify `User` as a type argument to `DeserializeObject`, the JSON does not match up to the `User` class the OP has defined.  Your answer does not show how to deal with this mismatch at all, nor how to handle a list of Users.  That is the crux of the problem the OP is trying to solve here.

Comment: Back to the drawing board then. I'll do a bit more research into this. Thanks :)