# How to serialise a list of objects of different type with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

In an application written in c# I need to create a JSON string with a certain syntax.
The data to be serialised is a list of different objects.
The syntax looks like this (section of the whole string):

```
    "ShipmentUnit": [{
            ...
            "Services": [{
                    "Service1": {
                        "ServiceName": "service_1",
                        "Property1": "Value1",
                        "Property2": "Value2"
                    },
                    "Service2": {
                        "ServiceName": "service_2",
                        "Property3": "Value3",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to provide the data to be serialised in a suitable object structure and then serialise it with Newtonsoft.Json. Unfortunately, this does not work.

If I use an array for the list, the result looks like this:

```
    "ShipmentUnit": [{
            ...
            "Services": [
                    {
                        "ServiceName": "service_1",
                        "Property1": "Value1",
                        "Property2": "Value2"
                    },
                    {
                        "ServiceName": "service_2",
                        "Property3": "Value3",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

If I use a dictionary, the result looks like this (the square brackets are missing):

```
    "ShipmentUnit": [{
            ...
            "Services": {
                "Service1": {
                    "ServiceName": "service_1",
                    "Property1": "Value1",
                    "Property2": "Value2"
                },
                "Service2": {
                    "ServiceName": "service_2",
                    "Property3": "Value3",
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

I've already read the following topics, but they do not match my problem:

[Serialise list of C# custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888150/serialise-list-of-c-sharp-custom-objects)

[Serialise list of objects to single JSON object, with property as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889203/serialise-list-of-objects-to-single-json-object-with-property-as-key)

[Serialise List<Dictionary<String,Object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897894/serialise-listdictionarystring-object)

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: How about using a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]`?

Comment: If you do get them serialized, you will find that deserializing them is more, uh, _interesting_.  Take a look at this (and the links within): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013538/deserialize-polymorphic-json-object-with-newtonsoft

Comment: For deserialization see specifically [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182),.  Your JSON will not include `"$type"` properties so you will need to create a converter that selects the type to deserialize from the `ServiceName` property.

Comment: I do not have to deserialice the data. The JSON string is send as a web request to an server.

Comment: Then `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]` (or `List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>`) as suggested by @JohnathanBarclay would seem to do it.

Comment: Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]? I will try this. I have tried several variants of nesting arrays, dictionaries and wrapping data types, but not this one.

Comment: List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>  it was.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Data data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
    
    json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public List<ShipmentUnit> ShipmentUnit { get; set; }
}
public class ShipmentUnit
{
    public List<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>> Services { get; set; }
}
```

result

```
{
  "ShipmentUnit": [
    {
      "Services": [
        {
          "Service1": {
            "ServiceName": "service_1",
            "Property1": "Value1",
            "Property2": "Value2"
          },
          "Service2": {
            "ServiceName": "service_2",
            "Property3": "Value3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```